# R markdown web page hosted on github does not reflect _site.yml

Tags: r, github, r-markdown

I am using this tutorial to create a R markdown web page hosted on github: http://nickstrayer.me/RMarkdown_Sites_tutorial/

I created _site.yml, Index.Rmd, and build_site.R exactly as in the tutorial (copy/pasted). When I open index.html in a web browser from my local directory, index.html reflects the _site.yml style and appears as expected based on the tutorial (navigation bar at top, same as in the tutorial).

However, when I upload the index.html to github and view the page through the repository web page address as in the tutorial, the style is lost. There is no navigation bar, and the menu items just appear as text links.

I tried using multiple browsers, and the issue remained.

Result when index.html opened locally:
[image: Result when index.html opened locally:]

Result when same index.html opened via github repository web page:
[image: Result when same index.html opened via github repository web page:]

- repository: https://github.com/jjwill2/jasonwilliams
- rendered site: https://jjwill2.github.io/jasonwilliams/

Comment: Can you post a link to the repository? BTW, these days I would suggest using the blogdown package, together with hosting on netlify. Really easy to setup!

Comment: https://github.com/jjwill2/jasonwilliams

Comment: Thanks. How do you view the published site? I get a 404 error at http://jjwill2.github.io/.

Comment: https://jjwill2.github.io/jasonwilliams/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your locally rendered site contains a directory `site_libs`. Files from this directory are [used within the HTML pages](https://github.com/jjwill2/jasonwilliams/blob/a24c57b68ca76c260027a9045527e4a5dc6f19dd/index.html#L19-L25), but you have not committed (or pushed) them to the git repository on Github. Once you commit these files and push them to github, the problem should go away.

A good debugging technique for these sort of issues are the developer tools build into modern browsers. The network view in FF gives the following upon loading your page:

[image]